# Identifying a group

Tags: group-theory, field-theory

**When asked to identify the group $\mathbb{F}_4^{+}$, is my explanation below complete? If not, how can I complete it?**

The field $\mathbb{F}_4^{+} = \mathbb{F}_2[x]/(x^2+x+1)$ consists of the residues $0, 1, x, x + 1.$ We construct a table to illustrate how the residues add:

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|l|l|} \hline
+   & 0   & 1   & x   & x+1 \\ \hline
0   & 0   & 1   & x   & x+1 \\ \hline
1   & 1   & 0   & x+1 & x   \\ \hline
x   & x   & x+1 & 0   & 1   \\ \hline
x+1 & x+1 & x   & 1   & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

Comment: This is isomorphic to a well-known group: can you identify that group by a more familiar name? It has two that occur to me.

Comment: Either $\mathbb{Z}_4$ or the Klein-$4$ group?

Comment: Those are not the same as each other. One of them is correct; can you tell which one? Look at the orders of the elements.

Comment: It would be the Klein-$4$ group, since each element has order $2$, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.